# How do I call a function in another javascript file when receiving a webhook in server.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, webhooks

I have a project which uses express to receive webhooks which are sent to a specific url. The project contains also a index.html which implements (via  tag) the script game.js with a simple tic tac toe game. To this point everything works fine: the webapp is displaying, the tic tac toe game is working and if a webhook is received `console.log(req.body);` is getting executed.

**Now to my question:**

I want that when server.js is receiving a webhook that in the game.js the function `webhookEvent()` gets called. But I have no idea how to achieve this as I am pretty new to javascript/node js. I don't understand how I can call a function in game.js from server.js. I would be pleased if somebody can help me with that.

---

The project has following folder structure and file contents:

```
project
  │   server.js
  │   package.json  
  │
  └───src
  │   │   index.html
  │   │   game.js
```

server.js (**start script**):

```
const express = require("express");
var app = express()
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html'));
});

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post("/webhook", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

var listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
  console.log("Your bot is running on port " + listener.address().port);
});
```

package.json (***sets server.js to start script***):

```
{
  "name": "project",
   ...
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  ...
}
```

src/index.html (***implements game.js at the bottom***):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...
</head>
  <body>
    ...
    <script type="module" src="game.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

src/game.js (***here I want to do something if server.js receives a webhook***)

```
if (document.querySelector) {
  document.documentElement.classList.add("js");

  var ticTacToeElement = document.querySelector("#tic-tac-toe");
  ...
}

function webhookEvent() {
  // do something when webhook is received
}
```

What I have already tried:

- export `app` from server.js `module.exports = app;` --> issue when I try to import this in game.js with `var app = require("../server.js");` the script game.js is not working anymore.
- export `webhookEvent` from game.js with `export {webhookEvent};` and import it in server.js --> I think this does not work because server.js is called before game.js and therefore can't import functions from game.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) which allow you to communicate back-and-forth between the server & client. I put together a very [simple Websockets sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/simple-chat-react17-websockets-express-q3x118) for you to understand and try implementing in your code.

There are many Websocket libraries to choose from, such as [Socket.io](https://socket.io/), [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws), etc. The example I provided has a React frontend and Express + Node backend. Even if you don't use React, the concepts are the same.

`index.js`

```
import express from "express";
import WebSocket, { WebSocketServer } from "ws";
import http from "http";

const heartbeat = (ws) => {
  ws.isAlive = true;
};

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 4443 });

wss.on("close", function close() {
  console.log("closed");
});

wss.on("open", function connection(client) {
  console.log('sent "open" to client');
  client.send("open");
});

// USER CONNECTED (onload events)
wss.on("connection", async function connection(client, request) {
  console.log("user connected", Date.now());
  client.send(JSON.stringify({ ready: true }));

  // CLIENT ALIVE-CHECK
  client.isAlive = true;
  client.on("pong", () => heartbeat(client));

  // message all clients in the ui
  client.on("message", async function message(d, isBinary) {
    if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
      const data = JSON.parse(d.toString());
      console.log("client message", { data });
      client.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          score: Math.random(),
          session: Math.random(),
          ...data,
        })
      );
    }
  });
});

server.listen(process.env.port || 4444, () => {
  console.log(`*~~% wesley's server %~~*`);
});
```

In your frontend you then make a connection to the Websocket server and setup your `listeners`. These allow your frontend to know when your backend sent it a message. Likewise, on the server there are listeners that let it know when the client `emit` or sent a message.

`websocket.addEventListener("message", (e) => {});`